# Hide a value in the List in razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I am new to C#. I have a list of values which are being shown in UI. I would like to hide a single element from the list. We need to hide it based on the environment  variable which comes fromt the yml file.
I want to hide the *make a payment* value from the UI

```
private readonly List<QuickAction> _quickActions = new()
{
       new QuickAction
    {

        Title = "Make a payment",
        Link = "/pay",           
        
    },
    new QuickAction
    {
        Title = "Split a bill",
        Link = "#",
        
    },
    new QuickAction
    {
        Title = "View reports",
        Link = "/reports",
       
    }
    
};
```

This list is called in quickaction card and it acts like a drop down where the list values come.

```
        <div class="mat-layout-grid-cell-span-3">
                        <QuickActionCard AccountType=@AccountType.ToString()
                                                Classes="p-0"
                                                Styles="border-radius: 10px !important;"
                                                QuickActions="_quickActions"
                                                ColumnSpanWidth="12" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: What is  `QuickActionCard` in your code?Can you share more about it?

Comment: its like a drop down where the list of values are shown in UI

Comment: Can you share where can get QuickActionCard?With third party css and js?